# Reset backlog after calling Listen in C# Socket programming

Tags: c#, sockets

I have an issue that: Can I reset `backlog` value of a server in running time, after I have called `Listen(backlog)`.

The purpose is to design a server that can allow the user to re-assign the maximum number of connections waiting to be accepted; without restarting the server.

Is there a solution for this?

[updated]
I have tested as Andrew suggestion.

Server:

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
IPAddress hostIPAddress = entry.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(hostIPAddress, 3200);

sock.Bind(localEndPoint);
Console.WriteLine("Server start");

sock.Listen(1);
Console.WriteLine("Backlog is one.");

Console.ReadKey();

sock.Listen(3);
Console.WriteLine("Backlog is three");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Client.cs

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
IPAddress ipAddress = entry.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint serverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3200);

Console.WriteLine("Enter port number: ");
int port = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
sock.Bind(localEndpoint);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Client start. IPAdress: {0}, Port: {1}", ipAddress, port));

try
{
    sock.Connect(serverEndpoint);
}
catch (SocketException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
Console.WriteLine(sock.Connected.ToString());

Console.ReadKey();
```

Result in console:

Server.exe

> Server start.
>
> Backlog is one

Client.exe (instance 1)

> Enter port number: 9900
>
> Client start. IPAdress: 127.0.0.1:3200 Port: 9900
>
> True

Client.exe (instance 2)

> Enter port number: 9901
>
> Client start. IPAdress: 127.0.0.1:3200, Port: 9901"
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:3200
>
> False

Then enter key for server, close Client.exe (instance 2)

Server.exe

> Backlog is three

Client.exe (instance 2)

> Enter port number: 9901
>
> Client start. IPAdress: 127.0.0.1:3200, Port: 9901"
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:3200
>
> False

Client.exe (instance 3)

> Enter port number: 9902
>
> Client start. IPAdress: 127.0.0.1:3200, Port: 9902"
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:3200
>
> False

Seems like `Listen(3)` not work.

Comment: Have you TRIED to do this yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9999));
sock.Listen(1);
sock.Listen(3);
}
```

For more references on .NET Sockets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen.aspx

Comment: Is this documented to work or did you test it? That would make the answer authoritative.

Comment: The extent to my testing was: I ran it... and it didn't throw an exception.

Comment: Good enough for me. +1

Comment: @Andrew: I have tried as your suggestion but it does not work as I expected.
First sock.Listen(1) accept just one pending connection, it's ok.
Then call sock.Listen(3) but second connection still be rejected.

Comment: You should add that code to your question so we can look at it.